# OTRS GenericTicketConnectorSOAP.wsdl can't create port and service

Tags: maven, wsdl, jax-ws, otrs

I'm using jax-ws maven plugin for generate obiekt from [GenericTicketConnectorSOAP.wsdl](http://paste.ofcode.org/4kMJ48CXqV7twGsdvaiBCE) every object generated without GenericTicketConnectorSOAP, service and port. My [pom.xml](http://paste.ofcode.org/WuAkkzLRSdmEipMkj6Va9z)  is wrong or this wsdl isn't prepare to generate service and port ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot use wsdl to generate Java stub classes. I posted my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28456702/otrs-error-generating-java-sei-with-wsdl/28506481#28506481)

BTW, the link to your pom does not work. Access denied.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your solution. I found other. When I'm using `axistools-maven-plugin` plugin

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>axistools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <urls>
                    <url>file:/${project.basedir}/otrs/Service.wsdl</url>
                </urls>
                <packageSpace>my.package</packageSpace>
                <testCases>false</testCases>
                <serverSide>false</serverSide>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

everything are generating by itself(port, service itp)